# Monitor cpu usage after crash

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, perfmon

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 on a dedicated server that I can only access via RDP or to turn on and off via power control. My server keeps crashing and I am not sure why. I looked at event viewer and there are many audit failures all day long. I've installed RDPGuard and I see a lot of IPs getting blocked. I'd like to know if there is anyway to get CPU and memory usage after I've hit the kill switch and start up the server via power control? Can I set perfmon to keep a history of this information?

Answer (score -1):

> Monitor cpu usage after crash....I'd like to know if there is anyway to get CPU and memory usage after I've hit the kill switch

Unfortunately the answer is no.  Once you power off the server it's no longer using CPU or memory resources.  Even if you could monitor resource use after this point there wouldn't be any usage to monitor.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?